# Dymanic Block based on Segments in phtml

Tags: magento2, blocks, phtml

I created 2 **dynamic** cms blocks in BE with different Customer Segment,
How can I call to them from phtml file?

Please note that dynamic cms block != cms block

[image: dynamic cms block]

tried

```
$block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier_cms_block')->toHtml();
```

But it works for static cms block

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier_cms_block')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: it works for static block, not for dynamic

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic ans static block ?

Comment: check screen in description